# selective transposing in excel using VB

Tags: vb.net, excel-2010, visual-studio-2010

I am creating an Excel worksheet using VB for a large chunk of data, currently represented by ~ 9500 rows of data in just one column (A1). Each logical record is actually 20 rows of the data.

What I need is:

1. Select 20 rows of data.
2. Copy that selection, then TRANSPOSE onto row one, starting at A1 and going through T1.
3. Then Delete the rows of data that were transposed into row 1 columns (basically delete 20 rows)
4. Then select the NEXT 20 rows of data, and repeat the whole process, but this time pasting into row 2 instead of row 1 (A2:T2).
5. This needs to iterate through the whole worksheet until it cycles through all 9500 rows.
6. The end result will be 475 rows of data, with values in the first 20 columns.

Comment: So why are you putting the data in a single column in the first place?

Comment: @DominicKexel : I am searching a large chunk of data using VB & generating an excel wherein the searched values are pasted. These are pasted along column A1 in Excel.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to group your data *before* writting it into the excel sheet?

Comment: this is the code I'm using for searching the data out of the text file:

` For Each line In File.ReadLines(RichTextBox3.Text)
                    Dim match = Regex.Match(line, pattern)
                    ' check each line and fill sheet

                If match.Success Then
                    sheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = match.Value

                    i += 1`

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday with another account, [slyclam](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681983/tricky-transposing-excel-sheet-from-vb-2010)?

Comment: Check this out, It has some nice code that you might give you some hints. [VBA Macro - selective copy and transpose](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/649210-visual-basic-applications-macro-selective-copy-transpose.html)